# How to split a string into fixed length chunks, but not in between words?

Tags: java, split, guava

I'd like to split some long sentences into fixed length chunks. So far I use guava for it:
`Splitter.fixedLength(20).split(string);`

Fine, but how can I prevent splitting in between words? My goal is to split to a maximum of 20 chars, but less if the splitpoint is not a whitespace.

Comment: I'm sure you could do it with a for loop, checking each character from the 20th character down until you find a white space

Comment: There isn't a magic one-liner for this. What have you tried?

Comment: Well there is already the online presented above, just it doesn't takes the word boundaries into account.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to split into chunks of some maximum length, splitting *only* between words.  (This would be the standard problem of "flowing" a paragraph of formatted ext.)  Otherwise your request makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `org.apache.commons.lang3.text.WordUtils.wrap()` to be exactly what I requested.

Answer (score 2):

I would split at white space, then combine the words that can be combined.

```
String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");         //get arr of strings by whitespace
List<String> split = new ArrayList<>();   //final list of tokens
for(int i =0; i<arr.length-1; i++){       //for all but the last word
    String s = arr[i];
    int len = s.length();             
    String newString = s;
    while(len < 20){                      //keep adding to the word until there are 20 chars
       if(len+arr[i+1].length()<19){      //if 2 words + space <20...
          newString+=" "+arr[i+1];        //add the two words plus a space
          len = newString.length();       //sets the value of len to the current string length
          i++;                            //skip that word, its been added!
       }
    }
    split.add(newString);                 //add either original word, or combined word.
}
return split;
```

Comment: Maybe you want to split on `\\s+` to get all kinds of whitespace

Comment: you are not changing the value of the variable length? I think there is a problem there. The while loop would continue infinitely.

Comment: just fixed it... see if there is any other problem in the code

Comment: I believe that this code could still run into an infinite loop never exiting the if statement.  Consider the case where len + arr[i+1].length() == 19.  In this case the outer while loop cannot be broken out of because len < 20.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)(.{1,19}(\\s|$)|\\S{20}|\\S+$)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String part = m.group(1);
    ...
}
```

Regex:

```
(
    .{1,19}(\\s|$)      upto 19 chars with space at end or end-of-string
                        could use word boundary \\b
|
    \\S{20}             20 non-chars
|
     \\S+$              at the end
)
```

Comment: this was the solution that I was trying to make. The best one I guess.

Comment: protip: `{20,20}` can be expressed as `{20}`.  Save a few chars.

Comment: Maybe add dot all flag to let `.` be also line separators.

Comment: @4aRkKn1gh7 not the most efficient, see AdamYost.

Comment: @JoopEggen correct me if i'm wrong but pattern matching doing something similar at the backend? I thought that pattern matching is more efficient apart from the fact that you get to write very little code.

Comment: It certainly is slower in general, one would need to test it on a larger scale, and compare it with a version, that even does not use split (regex too). However you are right: the code is much less error prone. A comment as above, explaining the regex helps, and a unit test too. An algorithm with `indexOf(' ', pos)` would be feasible too.